# How can i display a image in html?

Tags: html, image

I've tried to display the image by  tag and the location of image is in same directory in which html file is saved but still it shows only the alternative name(alt), not the image.

Here is my code :

```
<!DocTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My link Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>The link is below </h1></br>
        <a href="google.com">Google</a>;
        <img alt = "bittu" scr = "v.jpg" / >
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: <!DocTYPE html>

<html>
        <head> <title> My link Page</title> </head>
         <body> <H1>The image is below </h1>
                   
                     <img alt = "bittu" scr = "v.jpg" / >


           </body>
</html>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in an attribute name, the image link is in attribute `src` not `scr` :

```
<img alt = "bittu" src = "v.jpg" / > <!-- SRC -->
```